# how to return a response object json in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

i already get response but i'm not need it like this

```
{
  "status": "200",
  "id": 1,
  "email": "a@a.a",
  "mobile": "",
  "source": "",
  "source_id": "",
  "message": "Bad Request : Already Logged In"
}
```

i'm need return this data in anather object like :

```
{
 {
  "status": "200",
 }
 { 
  "id": 1,
  "email": "a@a.a",
  "mobile": "",
  "source": "",
  "source_id": "",
  "message": "Bad Request : Already Logged In"
 }
}
```

Comment: And what's the issue? what have you tried so far?

Comment: The second one is invalid json format. And I don't think so, the first one has any issue in parsing. But you use the format like {
   "status": "200",
   "details": { 
       "id": 1,
       "email": "a@a.a",
       "mobile": "",
       "source": "",
       "source_id": "",
       "message": "Bad Request : Already Logged In"
    }
}

Comment: i already get this solution but stay in a problem with android developer he not need something like "details" , "data" and so on . he need a response contain a data directly like { "id" : 1 , "email" : "a@a.com , and so on  }
i hope you understand me , thank's

Comment: @EsLaM While not answering directly, let me advertise ResponseBuilder package I created some time ago for Laravel to normalize and simplify wrting APIs with L: https://github.com/MarcinOrlowski/laravel-api-response-builder

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE (Feb 9, 2021):** If applicable, the best way to serialize your models into JSON is by using [Eloquent's API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources). This is especially useful when you're building RESTful APIs.

---

Use the `response()` and `json()` methods.

```
$data = [
    "status" => "200",
    "details" => [
        "id": 1,
        "email": "a@a.a",
        "mobile": "",
        "source": "",
        "source_id": "",
        "message": "Bad Request : Already Logged In"            
    ]
];

return response()->json($data);
```

This will return the following JSON:

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "details":  { 
        "id": 1,
        "email": "a@a.a",
        "mobile": "",
        "source": "",
        "source_id": "",
        "message": "Bad Request : Already Logged In"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not true at least on Laravel 6.x, just tried: you will get a JSON _array_, not an _object_. If you want to have more control, use `JsonResource` instead.

Comment: As of Laravel 10.x, it still returns a JSON array and not an object

Answer (score 2):

just return array json

```
return response()->json(['status'=>200,'data'=>$products]);



"status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "title": {
                "en": "Someone’s sitting in the shade today because someone planted a tree a long time ago.",
                "ar": "شخص ما يجلس في الظل اليوم لأن أحدهم زرع شجرة منذ زمن بعيد",
                "ca": "Alguien está sentado a la sombra hoy porque alguien plantó un árbol hace mucho tiempo."
            },
            "slug": {
                "en": "someone-s-sitting-in-the-shade-today-because-someone-planted-a-tree-a-long-time-ago",
                "ar": "شخص-ما-يجلس-في-الظل-اليوم-لأن-أحدهم-زرع-شجرة-منذ-زمن-بعيد",
                "ca": "alguien-esta-sentado-a-la-sombra-hoy-porque-alguien-planto-un-arbol-hace-mucho-tiempo"
            },
            "description": {
                "en": "Someone’s sitting in the shade today because someone planted a tree a long time ago.",
                "ar": "شخص ما يجلس في الظل اليوم لأن أحدهم زرع شجرة منذ زمن بعيد",
                "ca": "Alguien está sentado a la sombra hoy porque alguien plantó un árbol hace mucho tiempo."
            },
            "created_at": "2021-03-15T18:31:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-15T18:31:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "title": {
                "en": "Define success on your own terms, achieve it by your own rules, and build a life you’re proud to live.",
                "ar": "حدد النجاح بشروطك الخاصة، وتحققه بقواعدك الخاصة، واصنع حياة تفخر بأن تعيشها.",
                "ca": "Defina el éxito en sus propios términos, consígalo según sus propias reglas y construya una vida de la que se sienta orgulloso de vivir."
            },
            "slug": {
                "en": "define-success-on-your-own-terms-achieve-it-by-your-own-rules-and-build-a-life-you-re-proud-to-live",
                "ar": "حدد-النجاح-بشروطك-الخاصة-وتحققه-بقواعدك-الخاصة-واصنع-حياة-تفخر-بأن-تعيشها",
                "ca": "defina-el-exito-en-sus-propios-terminos-consigalo-segun-sus-propias-reglas-y-construya-una-vida-de-la-que-se-sienta-orgulloso-de-vivir"
            },
            "description": {
                "en": "Define success on your own terms, achieve it by your own rules, and build a life you’re proud to live.",
                "ar": "حدد النجاح بشروطك الخاصة، وتحققه بقواعدك الخاصة، واصنع حياة تفخر بأن تعيشها.",
                "ca": "Defina el éxito en sus propios términos, consígalo según sus propias reglas y construya una vida de la que se sienta orgulloso de vivir."
            },
            "created_at": "2021-03-15T18:31:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-15T18:31:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "title": {
                "en": "Never give up. Today is hard, tomorrow will be worse, but the day after tomorrow will be sunshine.",
                "ar": "لا تستسلم أبداً اليوم صعب، غدا سيكون أسوأ، لكن بعد غد سيكون شروق الشمس.",
                "ca": "Nunca te rindas. Hoy es duro, mañana será peor, pero pasado mañana habrá sol."
            },
            "slug": {
                "en": "never-give-up-today-is-hard-tomorrow-will-be-worse-but-the-day-after-tomorrow-will-be-sunshine",
                "ar": "لا-تستسلم-أبدا-اليوم-صعب-غدا-سيكون-أسوأ-لكن-بعد-غد-سيكون-شروق-الشمس",
                "ca": "nunca-te-rindas-hoy-es-duro-manana-sera-peor-pero-pasado-manana-habra-sol"
            },
            "description": {
                "en": "Never give up. Today is hard, tomorrow will be worse, but the day after tomorrow will be sunshine.",
                "ar": "لا تستسلم أبداً اليوم صعب، غدا سيكون أسوأ، لكن بعد غد سيكون شروق الشمس.",
                "ca": "Nunca te rindas. Hoy es duro, mañana será peor, pero pasado mañana habrá sol."
            },
            "created_at": "2021-03-15T18:31:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-15T18:31:02.000000Z"
        }
```

]

Answer (score 0):

```
Response(['status'=>'data','details'=>'data'], HTTP_OK);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Simply return the array:

```
$data = [
    "status" => "200",
    "details" => [
        "id": 1,
        "email": "a@a.a",
        "mobile": "",
        "source": "",
        "source_id": "",
        "message": "Bad Request : Already Logged In"            
    ]
];

return $data;
```

It will be parsed into a JSON response [automatically](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#json-responses) by Laravel:

> [..]  you may also return arrays. The framework will automatically convert the array into a JSON response