# Fusioncharts display data from controller where condition is count and groupBy using vue and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, charts

I have a doughnut chart and I want to display the count of the user based on the column `type`. In my controller, I got a query that returns the count. My problem is when I render the chart in my vue component, there are no data displayed. But when I look into my vue devtools, the data is shown but it is in a array/object format. Can someone know what should I do?

My controller

```
  $users = \DB::table('users')
                     ->select(\DB::raw('count(*) as type'))
                     ->groupBy('type')
                     ->get();
         return response()->json($users);
```

My script in vue component

```
 return {

            users: [],
            "type": "doughnut2d",
            "renderAt": "chart-container",
            "width": "550",
            "height": "350",
            "dataFormat": 'json',
            "dataSource": {
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "User Count", "theme": "fusion"
                }
                ,
                "data": [{
                    "label": "Admin Users",
                    "value": this.users
                }, 
               ]
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {

          getdata(){
           axios.get('api/graphs')
            .then(res=>{
                this.users = res.data;
                this.dataSource.data[0].value = this.users
            })
       }

    },
```

Vue devtools

[image]

The current count for the user type admin is `4` and the regular users is `2` which is correct. So the doughnut would be divided into two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also return the type of user so that dataSource.data.label is dynamic.

It should look like this.

```
dataSource.data.push({
    'label': res.data.typeUser
    'value': res.data.count
})
```

and In your dataSource.data

```
 "dataSource": {
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "User Count", "theme": "fusion"
                }
                ,
                "data":[]
            }
```

Please change your query.It should return the type and the count. Like this one. [how to return a response object json in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718385/how-to-return-a-response-object-json-in-laravel)

Comment: where should i put the `dataSource.data.push` objec sir? in compued?

Comment: Inside the axios then sir.

Comment: Wait ill make a chatroom

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201302/fusioncharts-vuejs-laravel join here